# divide and conquer algorithm

Tags: java, recursion, divide-and-conquer

I've been given a 2^k * 2^k sized board, and one of the tiles is randomly removed making it a deficient board. The task is to fill the with "trominos" which are an L-shaped figure made of 3 tiles.

The process of the solving it isn't too difficult.  If the board is 2x2, then it only takes one tromino to fill it.  For any greater size, it must be divided into quarters (making four 2^(k-1) sized boards), with one tromino placed at the center point, so each quadrant has one filled in tile. After that, the board can be recursively filled until every tile is filled with a random colored tromino.

My main problem is actually implementing the code. My skills with Java programming are generally pretty weak, and I often have trouble simply finding a place to start. The only work to be done is in the tile method in the tiling class, which takes as input the deficient board to tile, the row and column to start tiling in, and the number of tiles to fill. This is a homework problem, so I'm simply looking for some guidance or a place to start - any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
public class BoardViewer extends JFrame {

private static final int WIDTH = 1024;
private static final int HEIGHT = 768;
private static final int OFFSET = 30;

public static final int UPVERT = 1;
public static final int DNVERT = 2;
public static final int RHORIZ = 4;
public static final int LHORIZ = 8;
public static final int FILL = 16;

private Color [][] board;

public BoardViewer(DeficientBoard db) {
    super();
    setSize(WIDTH + (OFFSET*2), HEIGHT + (OFFSET*2));
    setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    setResizable(false);

    board = db.getBoardColor();
}

public void paint(Graphics g) {
    super.paint(g);

    int width = WIDTH/board[0].length;
    int height = HEIGHT/board.length;

    for (int r = 0; r < board.length; r++)
        for (int c = 0; c < board[r].length; c++) {
            g.setColor(board[r][c]);

            int x = c*width + OFFSET;
            int y = r*height + OFFSET + (OFFSET/2);

            g.fillRect(x+1, y+1, width-1, height-1);
        }
}
```

}

```
public class DeficientBoard {

private int n;
private Color board[][];

// The four rotations of the tile.
// UL is XX
//       X
// UR is XX
//        X
// LL is X
//       XX
// LR is  X
//       XX
public final int UL = 0;
public final int UR = 1;
public final int LL = 2;
public final int LR = 3;

/**
 * Create a 2^k x 2^k deficient board.
 * 
 * @param k power
 */
public DeficientBoard(int k) {
    n = (int)Math.pow(2, k);
    createBoard(Color.LIGHT_GRAY);
}

/**
 * Actually create an n x n deficient board.
 * 
 * @param color background color
 */
private void createBoard(Color color) {
    board = new Color[n][n];
    for (int r = 0; r < board.length; r++)
        for (int c = 0; c < board[0].length; c++)
            board[r][c] = color;

    int d_row = (int)(Math.random() * n);
    int d_col = (int)(Math.random() * n);
    board[d_row][d_col] = Color.BLACK;
}

/**
 * Given a row and column and shape based on that point
 * place a tromino of the given color.
 * 
 * @param r row
 * @param c column
 * @param s shape (UL, UR, LL, LR)
 * @param theColor a Color
 */
public void placeTromino(int r, int c, int s, Color theColor) {
    if (s == UL) {
        board[r][c] = theColor; 
        board[r][c+1] = theColor;
        board[r+1][c] = theColor;
    } else if (s == UR) {
        board[r][c] = theColor;
        board[r][c+1] = theColor;
        board[r+1][c+1] = theColor;
    } else if (s == LL) {
        board[r][c] = theColor;
        board[r+1][c] = theColor;
        board[r+1][c+1] = theColor;
    } else {
        board[r+1][c] = theColor;
        board[r+1][c+1] = theColor;
        board[r][c+1] = theColor;
    }
}

/**
 * Get the 2^k x 2^k board.
 * 
 * @return the Color board.
 */
public Color[][] getBoardColor() {
    return board;
}

/**
 * Find and return the deficient row.
 * 
 * @param row row
 * @param col column
 * @param sz size of the baord
 * @return the row the deficient block is located
 */
public int getDeficientRow(int row, int col, int sz) {

    for (int r = row; r < (row + sz); r++)
        for (int c = col; c < (col + sz); c++)
            if (board[r][c] != Color.LIGHT_GRAY)
                return r;

    return -1;
}

/**
 * Find and return the deficient column.
 * 
 * @param row row
 * @param col column
 * @param sz size of the baord
 * @return the row the deficient block is located
 */
public int getDeficientCol(int row, int col, int sz) {
    for (int r = row; r < (row + sz); r++)
        for (int c = col; c < (col + sz); c++)
            if (board[r][c] != Color.LIGHT_GRAY)
                return c;

    return -1;
}

/**
 * Get the size of the deficient board.
 * 
 * @return the size
 */
public int getSize() {
    return n;
}

/**
 * Display information about the deficient board.
 */
public String toString() {
    return ("Deficient board of size " 
             + n + "x" + n
             + " with position missing at (" 
             + getDeficientRow(0, 0, n) + "," + getDeficientCol(0, 0, n) +").");
}
```

}

```
public class Tiling {

private static Color randColor() {
    int r = (int)(Math.random() * 256);
    int g = (int)(Math.random() * 256);
    int b = (int)(Math.random() * 256);

    return new Color(r, g, b);
}

public static void tile(DeficientBoard db, int row, int col, int n) {


}

public static void main(String[] args) {

    DeficientBoard db = new DeficientBoard(3);
    System.out.println(db);

    tile(db, 0, 0, db.getSize());

    BoardViewer bv = new BoardViewer(db);
    bv.setVisible(true);

}
```

}

Answer (score 1):

In general, when a recursive function implements a divide-and-conquer algorithm, it has to handle two basic cases:

- The *base case*. This is the case where you're done dividing, and need to conquer a bit. In your assignment, the base case is the case where *n* = 2, and in that case, you just need to find which of the four tiles is missing/painted (using `DefectiveBoard.getDeficientRow` and `DefectiveBoard.getDeficientCol`) and add the appropriate triomino to cover the other three tiles.
- The *recursive case*. This is the case where you're *not* done dividing, so you need to divide (i.e., recurse), and (depending on the algorithm) may need to do a bit of conquering either before or after the recursion. In your assignment, the recursive case is the case where *n* > 2. In that case, you need to do two things:

  - Find which of the four quadrants has a missing/painted tile, and add the appropriate triomino to cover one tile from each of the other three quadrants.
  - Recurse, calling yourself four times (one for each quadrant).

A good starting point is to write the "Is this the base case?" check, and to implement the base case.

After that, if you don't see how to write the recursive case, one approach is to *temporarily* write a "one above the base" case (*n* = 4), and see if you can generalize it. If not, you might then *temporarily* write a "two above the base" case (*n* = 8), and so on. (Once you've got your recursive algorithm working, you would then remove these special cases, since they're fully covered by the general recursive case.)

Answer (score -1):

Well this is somewhat of a harder problem to solve.  However, I'd say you have the skills given how much code you wrote so I wouldn't be self conscious about it.

I don't have a complete solution formulated, but I think if you start at the the removed tile and put a trominos on either side of it.  Then keep putting trominos on either side of the last trominos.  You're "spooning" the tromino you last placed on the board.  Once you do that to the edge of the board.  All that's left is tromino shaped locations.  Here is an example of what I mean (X is the dropped tile ie the gap, Y are the trominos):

```
 _ _ _ _
|_|_|_|_|
|_|Y|Y|_|
|_|Y|X|Y|
|_|_|Y|Y|

 _ _ _ _
|Y|Y|_|_|
|Y|Y|Y|_|
|_|Y|X|Y|
|_|_|Y|Y|
```

Once the board is filled to the edges you can essentially start dropping trominos like bombs on the rest of the board.  I have a feeling there is a pattern here where you fill in the diagonal trominos while filling in the 2nd part at the same time that is repeatable.  But if you can't find that then create a recursive routine that spoons the gap to the edges then transitions to adding trominos in diagonal patterns.  The hint there is you have to do the transition in the first stack frame only.

Good luck.

Comment: -1, sorry. Your proposed algorithm is vastly inferior to the one the OP describes in the second paragraph of the question. I don't understand why you're suggesting it, unless you just completely misunderstood the OP's question. Re: "I'd say you have the skills given how much code you wrote": If I understand the question correctly, (s)he hasn't actually written *any* code yet; rather, the posted code is what was supplied as part of the homework problem, and the actual assignment is to implement `Tiling.tile`.

Comment: Well I did say I didn't have a complete solution, and I re read the post and there is no mention who authored the code.  The algorithm the OP described doesn't have enough detail how it decides to fill in the trominos, or the fact that you have to divide it recursively all boards to 4x4 and solve those, not 2x2.  So I think "vastly inferior" is a bit over dramatic given it wasn't fully described.